# grails hql left outer join

Tags: grails, left-join, hql

how is it possible to left outer join 2 tables?

```
class Person {

    String firstName
    String lastName
    String gender

    //static hasMany = [votes: Vote]

    static mapping = {
        version false
    }

    static constrains = {
    }

}
class Vote {

    Person voter;
    Person subject;

    static mapping = {
        version false
    }

    static constraints = {
        voter nullable: false
        subject nullable: false
    }


}
```

i need to get every person thats not subjected to a vote, for a specific person.
lets say person 1 votes for 3 out of 5 persons, i need the other 2 that he didnt vote for to show up for him.
How is the query supposed to be?

**EDIT:**

```
def personInstance1 = new Person(firstName: "Antonio", lastName: "Vivaldi", gender: "m")
def personInstance2 = new Person(firstName: "Dennis", lastName: "Rodman", gender: "m")
def personInstance3 = new Person(firstName: "Marc", lastName: "Oh", gender: "m")
def personInstance4 = new Person(firstName: "Gudrun", lastName: "Graublume", gender: "w")
def personInstance5 = new Person(firstName: "Hilde", lastName: "Feuerhorn", gender: "w")
def personInstance6 = new Person(firstName: "Mandy", lastName: "Muller", gender: "w")

personInstance1.save()
personInstance2.save()
personInstance3.save()
personInstance4.save()
personInstance5.save()
personInstance6.save()

def voteInstance1 = new Vote(voter: personInstance1, subject: personInstance2)
def voteInstance2 = new Vote(voter: personInstance1, subject: personInstance3)
def voteInstance3 = new Vote(voter: personInstance1, subject: personInstance4)
def voteInstance4 = new Vote(voter: personInstance1, subject: personInstance5)
def voteInstance5 = new Vote(voter: personInstance2, subject: personInstance1)

voteInstance1.save()
voteInstance2.save()
voteInstance3.save()
voteInstance4.save()
voteInstance5.save()
```

this is my grails bootstrap-file , Antonio and Dennis have voted, and each need to be presented a list of people they didnt vote for.

**EDIT:**
this way i seem to get a result for Dennis, since he only voted once,
but if i put v.voter_id = 1,
to get a result for Antonio, the result doubles according to how many votes he did.

```
 SELECT first_name FROM vote as v 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN person as p 
 ON v.subject_id != p.id AND v.voter_id = 2 
 WHERE p.id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: You want to know Muller has no voted by Vivaldi and so on?

Comment: yes :) muller should be returned to vivaldi as a possible candidate for voting...
and rodman should get returned everybody except for vivaldi.

Comment: included how far i got with the sql, but still hql syntax will be appreciated also, as mentioned in the title

Comment: Hi, show my update answer (about SQL), tell me if it's OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Person P
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 'Vote' FROM Vote V
    WHERE V.subject = P
)
```

In this way you'll extract all Person without Vote

**EDIT**

In SQL you can retrieve a matrix in this way:

```
CREATE TABLE #person (nome varchar(30))
CREATE TABLE #vote (votante varchar(30), candidato varchar(30))

INSERT INTO #person values 
('Antonio Vivaldi'),
('Dennis Rodman'),
('Marc Oh'),
('Gudrun Graublume'),
('Hilde Feuerhorn'),
('Mandy Muller')

INSERT INTO #vote values
('Antonio Vivaldi', 'Dennis Rodman'),
('Antonio Vivaldi', 'Marc Oh'),
('Antonio Vivaldi', 'Gudrun Graublume'),
('Antonio Vivaldi', 'Hilde Feuerhorn'),
('Dennis Rodman', 'Antonio Vivaldi')

SELECT *
FROM #person p
CROSS JOIN #person c
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 'X'
    FROM #vote v
    WHERE v.votante = p.nome
    AND v.candidato = c.nome
)
AND p.nome <> c.nome
ORDER BY p.nome
```

Comment: thanks, but this way i only get all persons without a subject id.
I actually need this for a specific person. For example person1 votes for 2 out of 5 persons and person 2 votes for 1 out of 5 persons, so results have to be different for each person.

Comment: @goran: Where I find a list of candidate? Because I think exist a Vote object if you have voted for that candidate, but if I don't vote about a candidate, I can't find it. If you have a list of candidate, we can begin by there

Comment: updated the post with some Person and Vote Instances

Comment: yes thanks a lot, this works, just one little problem:
now it gives back the results for everybody in the database.
how can i just have the results for one specific person, for example Dennis Rodman?

Comment: @goran: add anothere where condition before ORDER BY.

Comment: i put : WHERE p.nome = "Dennis Rodman" 
before ORDER BY 
and it throws an error

Comment: Dear, no WHERE but AND (WHERE is used before NOT EXISTS)